# Laravel Uploaded file path return error

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

i been following the upload method using this [tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) and i got some errors that i cant brain anymore.

Here are the example, i upload file name "fileNumber1.pdf", the laravel system will save the file using Storage facade.

```
$filePath[] = $fileData->storeAs('uploadedFile', $fileName);
```

So the original path will be "storage/app/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf".

To view the file, the tutorial suggest that to use

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

So from my understanding the echo should be like

```
echo asset('storage/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf');
```

Since i use local development the return is

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf
```

Then i go to the link given, it return

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

So how is the proper way to receive or view the file?

Comment: Seems like you forget to insert your /app/ folder to link.

Comment: @AndriiPryimak http://localhost:8000/app/storage/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf still the same.

Comment: Use storage/app/

Comment: Ohh, is not that easy, this is laravel. Not normal development. Already try, still same.

Answer (score 0):

This url `http://localhost:8000/` points to `pubilc` folder

So store your file inside `uploadedFile` folder inside `public` folder then use like

```
http://localhost:8000/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf
```

otherwise use `storage_path('uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf');` instead `asset('storage/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf');`

Comment: i using symlink system as laravel recommended. so the file will be keep in storage folder instead of public folder.

Comment: @Asyraf : are you storing in `public/storage` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would have followed the tutorial link then you should have run the below command which creates a symlink, If you haven't, do run that artisan command in your application folder.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

So now the below commad will give you desired result.

```
 {{ asset('storage/uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf') }}
```

or

```
{{ storage_path('uploadedFile/fileNumber1.pdf') }}
```

You don't have to point the complete path of your file because asset() will defaultly point you to public folder and then you have to add the required path of your file location.

Comment: already use the command for symlink at the very beginning. still the same.

Comment: Did you try both methods to call file? If so could you inspect element and show me the pointing path of the fie?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for all the rude if you receive.

The mistake is mine.

The solution was simple.

Original is

```
$filePath[] = $fileData->storeAs('uploadedFile', $fileName);
```

The solution is

```
$filePath[] = $fileData->storeAs('public/uploadedFile', $fileName);
```

Just add "public" before the file path before uploading.

Thanks all for the effort.